# Chromecast - issue - Each receiver currently casting should display, "Casting app name"

Tags: android, google-cast

What steps will reproduce the problem? (Point D)
1. Connect **chromecast** from **Youtube app**
2. Go to another chromecast app and click on media router button to see chromecast chooser dialog
3. in Chooser dialog List, connect chromecast device should  display current connected App name BUT IT DOESN'T

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Each receiver currently casting should display, "Casting app name"

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
Android 23
Support Lib - 23.2.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spg9w.png)

Please provide any additional information below.
I have tracked down the issue to the `MediaRouteChooserDialog` Line 290. Kindly check and let me know asap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PcAs.jpg)

Comment: Looks like a bug report for a totally different site

Comment: If you are stating that YouTube has a bug, I am not clear why you are reporting that here, please remove your post here and file a bug against YouTube if that is what you are claiming.

Comment: I am saying that (Android support Lib for)google cast  ahs a bug. I have posted it here to get the answer if anyone has found work around or not. Please read the post again (see the title of the post)